# Bulk loading RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is there a way to load multiple messages at the same time in RabbitMQ? I am trying to improve the performance of my app (a webserver which receives many http requests. For each request, I need to add approximately 500 messages to a queue).

Answer (score 0):

You can batch those messages into a single message, then process it on the backend appropriately.

Comment: Should I understand that there is no way to insert messages in bulk in rabbit?